# Continual listening of a linux device file in Python3

Tags: python, linux, file

I use device files to read entries with the `open()` and `f.read()` functions, but the problem is that `read()` doesn't stop until there is a new entry. So I can't let my program do anything else...

```
running = True

with open("/dev/input/js0", "rb") as f:
    while running:

        event = f.read(8)

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
```

For example, here I can only draw the window if the device is used.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use Python's [select.poll](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html#select.poll) method, which lets you check to see if a file descriptor has any input available.  We could rewrite your code something like this:

```
import select
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.display.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
poll = select.poll()

with open("/dev/input/js0", "rb") as f:
    poll.register(f, select.POLLIN)

    while running:
        events = poll.poll(0)
        if events:
          event = f.read(8)
          print('FLIP!')
          pygame.display.flip()

        clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
```

For more reading, look for articles on "non blocking io" with Python.

---

Alternately, you could use Pygame's event handling code rather than reading directly from `/dev/input/js0` yourself.  For example:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.joystick.init()
pygame.display.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
js = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
js.init()

running = True

while running:
    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        break

    if event.type == pygame.JOYHATMOTION:
        print('FLIP!')
        pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
```

The above code will only react to hat pressed, but you could easily extend it to listen to axis and button actions as well.